# MySQL count where age < x

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count all rows in a table where an integer is bigger than a specific value. How to do it?

Example:

```
If the table looks like
(name) |(age)
-------------
Marvin | 25
Bob    | 30
John   | 45

I want to count how many people are younger than 40.
```

It should return an integer only.

Comment: There is everything you need - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: `select count(*) from table where age < 40`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM Table
WHERE age < 40